# Open Watcom error cannot execute(wpp): No such file or directory*

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, dos, 16-bit, watcom

So I'm trying to create a 16bit MSDOS applcation with Open Watcom FORTRAN.

I created a new project and made a simple hello world cpp file but when I'm trying to build by hitting f4 it slams me in the face with the error:

*Error(E14): Cannot execute(wpp): No such file or directory*

I googled it several times but couldn't find any answers to my problem.
P.S: I'm using Watcom with the gui not in commandline

*This continues from the preceding discussion here, which was left unanswered
[How do I write a c++ console exe which I can run on msdos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806330/how-do-i-write-a-c-console-exe-which-i-can-run-on-msdos/12806416)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "hitting F4"?  Is this a shortcut in your IDE or editor?  If so, what IDE/editor are you using?

Regarding OpenWatcom, their [wiki](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page) contains a wealth of information.  I recommend making that your first stop when you run into problems.  For your particular case, the [Reference Manuals](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Reference_Manuals) page will be useful.  See chapter 3 of the "Getting Started Guide" for a walkthrough of creating and building a program using OpenWatcom's IDE.  If you are building your code using your own makefiles or build scripts, see the "User's Guide" for details on calling the compiler directly from the command line.

The "Programmer's Guide" contains sample projects (including compilation instructions).  The "samples" folder inside your OpenWatcom install directory contains a number of sample projects, all with makefiles or build instructions.  You can probably use one of these as a template for your project.

Comment: Also, there is a batch file in the root of the OpenWatcom install directory named "owsetenv.bat" that sets up your environment.  Instead of building through your IDE/editor, open a command prompt, run that script, and then call your makefile or build script manually.  That should ensure that your environment is set up the way that the tools are expecting.

Comment: Alright I'll try that out when I get back from work. It's been a bussy week! Thanks for your help